# wechat pay returnKey null value in iOS

Tags: ios, null, payment-gateway, wechat

I m trying to implement `WeChat` pay, everythings done but when i PayReq send than `WeChat` app will open and than just this kind of image show with just only ‘Ok’ button and when i click on ok button than it returns back to my app and get ‘(null)’ return key.

Return message is:

//Code:

```
PayReq* req             = [[[PayReq alloc] init]autorelease];
        req.partnerId           = [dicParams objectForKey:@"mch_id"];
        req.prepayId            = [dicParams objectForKey:@"prepay_id"];
        req.nonceStr            = [dicParams objectForKey:@"nonce_str"];
        req.timeStamp           = timeStamp;
        req.package             = @"Sign=WXPay";
        req.sign                = [dicParams objectForKey:@"sign"];
        [WXApi sendReq:req];
```

Return value :

```
://pay/?returnKey=(null)&ret=-2
```

**Check Screen ::**[image]

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the code you use to trigger the payment...

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation for their API, do you have a link? Did you check what error `-2` means? Did you properly add the Wechat-specific code in `handleOpenURL:`? Have you check that your parameters are valid?

Comment: @jcaron Yes. All parameters are valid but still getting issue.

Comment: The other questions remain.

Comment: @jcaron everything is okay.

Comment: @jcaron Wechat-specific code in handleOpenURL: code is [WXApi handleOpenURL:url delegate:self]

Comment: please check your email @BhaveshNayi ji.

Comment: @dip if you use wechatpay in your app then apple reject your app.